# Asp.Net using QuickBooks SDK with multiple accounts

Tags: asp.net, quickbooks

Working on an asp.net website. We would like the ability to upload data from our website to QuickBooks. Problem is users of this website will ALL have different QuickBooks online accounts, thus our website must be able to communicate with multiple QuickBooks accounts. Is this possible?? Also, can we do this without each user setting up a QuickBooks app and getting a consumer secret, consumer key, and security key???

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Problem is users of this website will ALL have different QuickBooks online accounts, thus our website must be able to communicate with multiple QuickBooks accounts. Is this possible??

Yes, of course.

> Also, can we do this without each user setting up a QuickBooks app and getting a consumer secret, consumer key, and security key???

Yes, of course.

You should be setting up *ONE* application. Then *each* individual QuickBooks Online company file has their admin user go through the connection process, giving you a different *access token* and *access token secret* for each individual *QuickBooks Online company* that you want to access.

Comment: Thanks Keith. You have confirmed what I originally suspected. We were hoping to avoid having an admin run through a connection process and make the process more automated, but it seems this is unavoidable. Thanks for the quick response to my first stack overflow question.

Comment: If Intuit allowed you to connect, totally unauthenticated, to any random QuickBooks Online account that you wanted to... wouldn't it be a gigantic security hole?  Why would you be opposed to requiring the admin to click two buttons, just once, to get connected? It doesn't get much more automated or simple than that...